# (Laravel 3.2) Artisan task in Cron Job not running?

Tags: php, cron, laravel

I am trying to have this Artisan task run as a cron job (host is Bluehost):

```
    php-cli /home3/***/***/artisan task
```

this works from the command line (SSH), but not with Cron.
I know it doesn't execute because it's supposed to add a DB entry.

What is wrong there?

EDIT::As there are no errors reported anywhere (either to email or to an output.log file), 
I would guess the command executes, but fails to do anything.
Can that be because of a database connection issue in the Artisan Task?
There is a simple DB::('table)insert(etc) in there..

But if the task works from the command-line, why not from Cron?

Comment: Have you tried catching an exception manually and log it somewhere? Or just log in the beginning of your task, if it is really executed, so maybe this is not an Laravel related problem.

Comment: What do you mean catch an exception manually?

Comment: Writing a big `try{...}catch(Exception $e){...}` around your task.

Comment: @user1924460 did you solve it? Care to share?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making a php page in a sub directory (something like : /tasks_to_execute/task.php) with the php script on it with "echo 'task successful!'" at the end, and the cronjob on bluehost just "lynx" to it.

Soo no I didn't figure out why it didn't work as an artisan task. I just figured a way around it, quick fix. The security issue of having the script as a "public" page doesn't really matter as the script executes every half hour anyways and just updates a database from a facebook feed.

Answer (score 0):

I faced  similar problem. Try using with the full path to the php this: /usr/local/bin/php /home/mysitename/laravel/artisan schedule:run